# Running Apache Drill Cluster in Windows?

Tags: apache-drill

I'm just playing around with Apache Drill for the first time using the nice documentation from the Apache site. I was able to play with it in embedded mode using the sqlline.bat file to start it. However when it comes to distributed mode, the instructions are specific to a unix system - running a Drillbit using a shell command.

Is there anyway for me to play around with Apache Drill cluster using two Windows boxes?

If so, how do I start the Drillbits on each client without being able to run that drillbit.sh file?

Comment: Zookeeper is one of the [prerequisites](https://drill.apache.org/docs/distributed-mode-prerequisites/) for running drill in cluster mode. Do you have zookeeper on your Windows boxes?

Answer (score 0):

The shell command can be run through [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).
Install it and add the path to it's `bin` directory to your `PATH` environment variable. 
Now assuming that you have the [Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) installed and set up on both your windows boxes, open up a command prompt on each box, navigate to the Apache Drill's `bin` directory and run the following command:

```
sh ./drillbit.sh start
```

Running the drillbits without the `drillbit.sh` is a hell of a task as the script resolves your complete classpath and declares some environment variables like `HADOOP_HOME` for execution to proceed.